# Angular CLI 1.0.0-rc.0 and routing between modules

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli

I created the following angular2 cli app:

ng new my-project --routing
ng g module team

So then I have the following structure:

```
--app
  --app.component.css
  --app.component.html
  --app.component.ts
  --app.module.ts
  --app-routing.module.ts
  --team
    --team.module.ts
    --team-routing.module.ts
    --team-detail
      --team-detail.component.css
      --team-detail.component.html
      --team-detail.component.ts
```

Basically I have two modules, AppModule and TeamModule, and I want to configure the routes between the two of them.
And I have the following setup in the routes right now (it is the default one when generating the modules with ng generate module [name] --routing):
app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: []
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

team-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {TeamDetailComponent} from "./team-detail/team-detail.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: ':id', component: TeamDetailComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class TeamRoutingModule { }
```

So, I do not know how to configure the routes that if I go to the url

{host}:{port}/team/:id

the component TeamDetailComponent handles it. But if I go to {host}:{port}/ then App handles it

Every thing I tried it leads to an error. What should I do? How should I configure the children? The documentation related to routes is not very clear, and I have tried several things I have seen in the web, but it leads to new errors every time, specially one saying that TeamDetailComponent is not declared in any module, despite that I declared it in the Team module.

Comment: I don't think this addresses your issue but I normally use `declarations: [ TeamDetailComponent ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's what you have to do, point the root routing module to your team module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    // Example route
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  }, {
    // Point the loadChildren to your team module
    path: 'team',
    loadChildren: 'app/team/team.module#TeamModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Now configure the routing on your second module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {TeamDetailComponent} from "./team-detail/team-detail.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',
    children: [{
      path: ':id',
      component: TeamDetailComponent
    }]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class TeamRoutingModule { }
```

This way your routing is split for the parent and child and even better the team module is now lazy loaded!

Note this is untested so there might be a small typo somewhere but this is how it should work!

Here is a great post about lazy loading
https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html